# How to show client side error and server side on one form properly?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I'm using RubyOnRails and jQuery validation plugin. I want to style all errors look the same.

Here is my code for errors:

```
 <% if @website.errors.any? %>//for server errors
  <div class="error_explanation">
  <ul>
    <% @website.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>  
 </div>
<% end %>
 <div id="messageBox1"> //for client side errors
  <ul></ul> 
</div>
```

I tried to wrap all in one form, but if do this:

```
    <div class="error_background">
      if ...server side ...
      end
     ... client site ...
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.error_background{
padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
width: 285px;
background: rgb(252, 248, 227) ;
border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

but it showing background when there are no server side errors.

How can I do this right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to look the same then all you have to do is to make a stile for both of them using comma in your css like this:

```
.error_explanation, #messageBox1 {}
```

And you should insert them into dom only when you have errors, or put your background on the  inside them

```
.error_explanation, #messageBox1 ul {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    width: 285px;
    background: rgb(252, 248, 227) ;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```